# I am trying to optimize my android application

Tags: java, android, optimization, multidimensional-array, togglebutton

I made a LightsOut game for a java course and as a way to learn android I am trying to rebuild it as an application.

The main activity consists of a grid of togglebuttons. When a button is "checked" it and its adjacent buttons are toggled. When all of the buttons are toggled off the game is won. I have made it work to this point but the code is horrendous.

I would like to clean the code up by making a two-dimensional array of togglebuttons. How I have it at the moment I simply declare each button individually. This makes for large blocks of redundant code and with no easy way to scale.

Originally, in java I did this:

```
    buttons = new LightButton[xCor][xCor];

    for (int x = 0; x < xCor; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < xCor; y++) {
            buttons[x][y] = new LightButton(this, x, y);
            panel.add(buttons[x][y]);
        }
    }
```

Where xCor was based on user input prior to construction of the gamefield. This made initializing and checking the status of the game easy by traversing the array. I simply have not found a way to do this with android.

So, is there a way to make an array/list of togglebuttons based on user input?

Here is the activity:

public class LightsOutActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
protected ToggleButton[][] buttonArray;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    buttonArray = new ToggleButton[4][4];

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            buttonArray[x][y] = new ToggleButton(this);
            LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f);
            buttonArray[x][y].setLayoutParams(params);

            ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.main)).addView(buttonArray[x][y]);
        }
    }



    setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.main));
}
```

The immediately results in a force close.
The only view in R.layout.main is a linearlayout. For now I've hard coded the array size.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you take user input from a EditText view? Then you can initialize your array with that input.

Comment: That's what I would like to do, yes. My primary problem is initializing an array of buttons/togglebuttons. It simply doesn't work for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong so I was hoping for an example to follow.

Comment: Okay. I added the onCreate() method to my original post above.